# Check what conda environment is currently activated

Tags: linux, bash, anaconda, miniconda

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to check which conda environment is currently activated.

I know you can do `conda env list` and the active environment will be printed with a *. 
However, I would like to do this programmatically as an input into an else if statement.

parsing the output of conda env list is rather inconvenient so I hope there is an easier way

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When a `conda` environment is activated, it will `export` following related environment variables:

- `$CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV`, name of current activated env
- `$CONDA_PREFIX`, path to the current activate env

Answer (score 17):

`conda info --envs`

###### This will print all the conda environments. The current environment will have an asterisk( ***** ) in front of it's name.

Comment: Or, just `conda info` will give you the current environment (and a lot of other useful info).

Comment: This should be the correct answer. The answer above is not working

Answer (score 7):

The current environment is stored in the environment variable, `$CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV`. So,

```
echo $CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV
```

will give the name of the current conda environment.