# Conda VIRTUAL_ENV environment variable

Tags: environment-variables, conda, zsh, python-venv

Is there are robust way to automatically update (or set) an environment variable `VIRTUAL_ENV` equal to the `CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV` environment variable? e.g. upon running `conda activate <env_name>` or `conda deactivate`?

Ideally when I create new environments I don't want to have to do anything extra, either. e.g. if I `conda create -n <env_name> && conda activate <env_name>` that should automatically update the `VIRTUAL_ENV` environment variable.

I would like to do this as a solution that works with any shell (currently using zsh on MacOS) theme that uses the `VIRTUAL_ENV` variable to modify the prompt display.

Answer (score 0):

Conda already updates the `CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV` variable at activation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58376001/4413446) for more information. It could be an easier / standard solution to modify your prompt display to use this variable instead of `VIRTUAL_ENV`?

```sh
# from the base env activate the prophet env
echo $CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV && \ 
  conda activate prophet && \
  echo $CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV
# base
# prophet
```

It is the code used by some well known zsh themes: [Starship](https://starship.rs) and [Spaceship](https://spaceship-prompt.sh).

```rust
// Reference implementation: https://github.com/denysdovhan/spaceship-prompt/blob/master/sections/conda.zsh
let conda_env = context.get_env("CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV").unwrap_or_default();
```

[from Starship code](https://github.com/starship/starship/blob/e18c61cd684f77b13c65647065304f5fdc6a4080/src/modules/conda.rs#L12)

If you want to stick to a custom variable you can create a script to wrap all the commands and define the v, but it's a bit hacky.

```sh
ENV_NAME=my-env
conda create -n $ENV_NAME -y && \
  conda env config vars set VIRTUAL_ENV=$ENV_NAME -n $ENV_NAME && \
  conda activate $ENV_NAME && \
  echo "$VIRTUAL_ENV"
# my-env
```

Comment: I think this is the *correct* solution, even though it doesn't technically answer my question, and I should probably just do this. It just means when I install a theme written by someone else, I'd need to modify it (if it only looks at `VIRTUAL_ENV` and not `CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV`). Not the end of the world I guess :)

Comment: @ogb119 Agree. However the conda hooks are per environment. I'm not 100% sure however setting variables at activate will probably look like a hack. If you are building a theme ou can manage both variables :-)

Comment: @ogb119 I had a look at the implementation of Starship & Spaceship zsh themes and they both use the variable `CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV`.