# conda saving environment variables for all environments

Tags: variables, environment-variables, conda

The [conda documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#saving-environment-variables) describes how to set/unset environment variables upon activation/deactivation of a specific environment.

Is there a way for this method to be applied globally, to all environments (including ones yet to be created), instead of having to manually do this process for every environment you create?

A less than ideal solution could be to write a shell script that will run through the process described in the documentation, but has to be triggered manually by me every time I create an environment. If possible I would like a solution that doesn't need any manual intervention at all.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on your use case? Conda environments (and other virtual environment solutions) are designed specifically to be isolated from each other and not leak things into the global/system state.

Comment: I asked it as a more specific question at the link below, hence why I deliberately kept this question general (in case someone else had a different use case)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70534480/conda-virtual-env-environment-variable